# Use encrypted page url from javascript to call .aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, encryption

I m using javascript-jquery/ajax calls for invoking the web page in my project. I m aware that my all the url is exposed to the javascript which i m willing to encrypt now. Can any one suggest me the best way to do the same? I m not sure if I should hard code the encrypted url and call the httphandler with encrypted url as query string and decrypt the same in code behind then call the web page. Will that be the correct way to do the same? Please help.

Thanks,
Akash

Comment: Why would an encrypted url be different from an unencrypted url? they are both still urls. If you want to encrypt post/get data use TLS for transport security. If you want to prevent unauthorised access implement authentication.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Alex. The reason i m willing to encrypt the url is because visibility of url(s) in java-script files will be source for hackers to information gathering about the hierarchy. This will be initial level for security breach. Encrypted url will be able to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Akash what you're after is obfuscation, not encryption. Even if the url is called /bG92ZWRhbW9tbWE= instead of /Delete, by observing your traffic one can easily figure out that this endpoint is delete. So i would just change the name Delete to 'do' or something similar. You need to focus on actually protecting the payloads and authenticating requests.

Answer (score 0):

> I m aware that my all the url is exposed to the javascript which i m willing to encrypt now. Can any one suggest me the best way to do the same?

[**Don't.** Encryption is the wrong tool for the job.](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php) What you want is a blinded look-up that maps a randomly generated value to the real value.

If you're not looking for obfuscation, any other concerns are almost certainly alleviated by using HTTPS (HTTP over TLS).